# Is it possible to add one more sample to the result of featureCounts?

Tags: subread

I have some .bam files and I also got featureCounts by Subread. But after getting the featureCounts I realized that among my bam files 2 of them actually belong to the same sample. So I wonder if I can remove the result of these two and after merging bam files add them again into featureCounts without doing all the featureCounts for other samples again.

Comment: Sure, `paste` and company will help or load it into R and cbind stuff as needed, but seriously, featureCounts is blazingly fast and even with many samples on a modest laptop it just takes minutes. Just rerun it. Given the 59min period of time that this question is here it would have been finished by now probably ;-) For code suggestions it is mandatory to add example data though.

Comment: It sounds like you are supplying multiple BAMs to featureCounts, while this is possible I think it's better to run featureCounts on each BAM separately and then use a Python script or `cbind` function in R as mentioned above to combine the results of multiple samples. This shall give you more flexibility.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the answers. As ATpoint mentioned I realized that featureCounts doesn't need much computational power and time. And good to know I can merge with Python or R script.